# How to fix the navbar hover issue CSS

Tags: css, navigation, navbar

I am working on navbar in bootstrap 4. I am experiencing issue when i hover on the nav links. I have added border bottom on hover for navlinks. But when the hover is made the entire navbar moves. I have pasted what i have done so far.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="#" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">First item</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Second Item</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="my-2 my-lg-0">
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<style>
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, 
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is shifting is because you have no border, and then all of a sudden a 2px border is added on hover. The way to fix this is by adding a 2px transparent border to the regular/unhovered state.

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: @tkamath99 No problem! You can press the check mark on the left side of my post to show it is the correct answer. If anyone else runs into a similar problem, it will make it easier to find the solution. Good luck!

Comment: To avoid an arbitrary transparent border, you could absolutely position a pseudo-element (e.g., `::after`) that has a border, only when the link is hovered (e.g., `.nav-link:hover::after`, with `position: absolute`, and `position: relative` on the link itself). This prevents adding 2px of arbitrary space and looks clean.

Comment: Interesting! I will try that myself sometime. Thank you for the input!

Comment: @dnmch can you pls explain a bit more. Thanks!